# List out of index - Python but it should not be

Tags: python, list

I was going through my lecture notes and was redoing an example the prof was doing in class. But I keep on getting a list out of index error. Any help or explanation would be great. I tried to read up on it but did not understand it hence am posting it here hoping that someone could explain it to me.

This is what I did:

```
def sortList(list1):


   sorted = [] 

   while len(list1)> 0:

     lowest = list1[0]

     for value in list1:
        #we need to place the items in order so first we will find the lowest value
        if value < lowest:
            lowest = value
        #lowest is the smallest number in list1
    # now we can add it to the sorted list

    sorted.append(lowest)

    #we can remove the item from list one
    list1.remove(lowest)

  return sorted

def median(list1):
  list1 = sortList(list1)
  #list one is now in sorted order

  while len(list1)> 2: # we are trying to take out all the numbers till 2 left (if 3 left it will execute and leave 1)
    list1.pop(0) #takes out the first item in the list
    list1.pop() #takes out the last item in the list

  if len(list1) == 1: # if there is only one item we return it
    return list1[0]
  else: #returns the avg of those
    return((list1[0] + list1[1])/2)



x = [45, -1, 0, 54, 101, 2, 7,11]

print(sortList(x))
print(median(x))
```

However when I do

```
print(sortList([45, -1, 0, 54, 101, 2, 7,11]))
print(median([45, -1, 0, 54, 101, 2, 7,11]))
```

it prints out fine. Why is that?

This is the error am getting: 
print(median(x)) ... return((list1[0] + list1[1])/2)
IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: Can you post your error traceback?

Comment: What's the exact problem with the first one? I feel like you neglected to mention that. Could you post a stack trace please?

Comment: btw, `sorted` is a built in function, you'd not want to overwrite it.

Comment: @KevinFang the prof did mention that sorted is a built in function. for this example, he used sorted as an empty list to help us understand what was happening in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the `x` has been modified in `sortList` function called at `print(sortList(x))` statement. If you check, the value of x after that statement is `[]`. Therefore, an empty list is inserted to `median` function, which causes out of index error when executing `return((list1[0] + list1[1])/2)` (since the length of empty list is 0 and 0 != 1)

`print(sortList([45, -1, 0, 54, 101, 2, 7,11]))` and `print(median([45, -1, 0, 54, 101, 2, 7,11]))` works because the `median` function did not get an empty list as the input.

Another reason is also because you are returning the sorted list from `sortList` function, but you are not storing it back to x. So, this should work

```
x = [45, -1, 0, 54, 101, 2, 7,11]
x = sortList(x)

print(x)
print(median(x))
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the explanation. This helps somewhat.

Comment: Edited my answer to include example

Comment: Thanks for the help. This definitely helped me understand the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your implementation of sortList() method. In that method **x** and **list1** are reference to same list and as you removing the elements from **list1** at the end of the method list **x** become empty list. so when you try to access elements from empty list `((list1[0] + list1[1])/2)`, it will give you index out of bound error.

You can visualize you code execution line by line [http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit](http://here)

Solution : copy list1 in new list in sortList(). you can use `new_list = old_list.copy()` or `new_list = old_list[:]`